# Spring MVC - Request Mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm very new using the Spring Framework.

I found a tutorial that showed me how to set up a simple login using Spring Security.
It also included some code for the view: home.jsp and controller: HomeController.java

they look like this:

home.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" type="text/css"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <a href=<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>>Logout</a><br/>

    <sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_ADMIN">
        <h1>Only admin can see this</h1><br/>
        <a href="admin"> Admin Home </a>
    </sec:authorize>

    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    Logged in as: <c:out value= **"${CurrentUser}"** /> !<br />
</body>
</html>
```

and HomeController.java

```
package rd.controller;

import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller

public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setUp(Model model){
        **model.addAttribute("CurrentUser", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());**

        return "home";
    }
}
```

From what I've gathered, the lines surrounded with ** are connected to make the attribute available for the jsp page to display. However there's something wrong with how I'm doing it and the website literally prints:

```
Logged in as: ${CurrentUser}!
```

I could use a logic check as well as an explanation of how Spring should be connecting the Controller and View. Also, any good Spring tutorial links are welcomed, Thanks!

Comment: Have u configured ViewResolver in spring config file?

Comment: That doesn't sound familiar so probably not. What config file are you referring to? pom.xml? or one of the security/login xml files?

Comment: Also double check what Servlet version you are using. Try version 2.4 or greater

Comment: @Christy spring context xml file is used to specify the details such as your controller file packages, view resolvers etc. Probably you need to learn a basic spring mvc tutorial before u jump into code.

Comment: @Juned Thank you, I didn't even realize I haven't configured any beans. Do you know any quick mvc tutorials that will cover the basics? Unfortunately, I have a very limited time to finish my website.

Comment: @Christy You can check this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm . Feel free to connect in case you need help.

Comment: @JunedAhsan So I apparently had ViewResolver:

<bean id="internalResourceResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

Does that configuration look right?
Also, how can I connect with you? If you don't mind, I'd love to pick your brain as I continue through the tutorial.

Comment: @Christy Have u mentioned <context:component-scan> property for your controller. First thing to check is whether you are able to reach your controller when you hit a URL. So put some traces/sysout in your controller method.

Comment: Could you post your web.xml as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
package rd.controller;

import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller

public class HomeController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/home" , method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView setUp(){
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
    **model.addObject("CurrentUser", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());**

    return model;
}
```

}